# How to use thrift file generation interface class in Scrooge

Tags: scala, scrooge

Like this command

```
thrift -r --gen py tutorial.thrift
```

Answer (score 0):

Configure Scrooge in SBT with the following dependency:

```
libraryDependencies += "com.twitter" %% "scrooge-core" % "4.3.0"
```

Then run it from command line like below:

```
$ ./sbt 'scrooge-generator/run-main com.twitter.scrooge.Main <thrift-file1> [<thrift-file2> ...]'
```

More details [here](http://twitter.github.io/scrooge/CommandLine.html).